# If $a = 5, $b = 'a', what is the value of $$b?

Tags: php

Explain this interview question to me:

**Q:** If the variable $a is equal to 5 and variable $b is equal to character a, what’s the value of $$b?

**A:** 5, it’s a reference to existing variable.

Comment: What's that `-100` doing there?

Comment: @Fernandes 100 is the answer!

Comment: why 100 is answer? is not  $$b should equal to 5?

Comment: The answer is -95 because `$b` is equal to `a`. When you do `$$` it becomes a variable, variable that makes the tokens name that value of `$b`, in this case that is `a`. The parser looks at it and it reads 5 - 100 because `$$b` is equal to `$a` is equal to 5.

Comment: Why would you add ? after $$b

I'm sure you mean $$b - 100, in which case its 95.

Comment: If 100 is the answer the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think the hyphen is only there to separate the interview question from the answer.

Comment: `?` is apart of the **Ternary Operator** but *REQUIRES* the presence of a colon (`:`) to complete the statement. So, I'm going to say no, it's not apart of the question, it's only punctuation.

Comment: A lower case `a` is `65` in it's decimal form, even `65 - 100` is still `-45`. The answer does not make any sense.

Comment: He has missed something... I think he wants t write as $$b - 100 the "-" is minus sign

Comment: **Q:** If the variable `$a` is equal to `5` and variable `$b` is equal to character `a`, what’s the value of `$$b`?

**A:** `$$b == 5`, because `$b = 'a'`, the parser turns `$$b` into `$a` that makes the value of `$$b` equal to `5`.

Comment: Hey! r u really team India cricketer or just making fun?? have any proof?

Comment: @ I Like PHP... Do you think Murali Vijay will be sitting in SO by now? Team moved to West Indies for the ICC World Twenty20 yesterday!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). PHP will look up the variable with the name stored in the string `$b`. So if `$b == 'a'` then `$$b == $a`.

It's a lot like pointers in C, except they use variable name strings instead of memory addresses to point to each other. And you can dereference as many times as you want:

```
$a = 5;
foreach (range('b', 'z') as $L) {
  $$L = chr(ord($L) - 1);
}
echo $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$z;
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 1):

`-95` is the answer as if u will `echo $b` u will get output as 
"`a`"
 and if u `echo $a` u will get out but as "`5`"

hence in this sense when u `$(echo $b)` which same as `$(a)` hence u will get it as "`5-100`" which is "`-95`"

Answer (score 0):

```
  $$b - 100
= $a - 100 // substituting $b=a
= 5 - 100
= -95
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a good reference on PHP variables

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the '?' is erroneous in the statement '$$b? - 100' but I don't think that will compile.

However:

```
$a = 5
$b = 'a';
$c = $$b - 100;
```

$c will equal -95, because $$b is a variable variable reference and given that $a = 5 it resolves to $a (5) - 100, or -95.

Comment: `$$b` is perfectly legal syntax

Comment: @webdestroya but `$$b?` is not

Comment: Yes I was referring to the '?' character from the '$$b? - 100' part of the question.  :)

Comment: @Mike B But `$$b?'foo':'bar'` would be. :o)

Comment: @deceze, but he did not say that in the question. He does not appear to be using the **Ternary Operator** at all, as it's missing the colon (`:`) in his question. I'm pretty sure the `?` part is just punctuation.

Comment: @Mark I know, I know. Half-humorous statements are difficult on a tech site... `<highlight>`:o)`</highlight>`

Comment: lol, sorry mate. It does not come over well without `<sarcasm>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is -95

```
$a - 100
```